# Finding the integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can i find the integrating factor of this equation 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{4y^2+2x}$$
knowing that is the form $\mu=\mu(y)$

I tried to separate in the form $\frac{dy}{dx} = a(x)y+b(x)$ but I don't know how to separate de $x$ from the $y$ in the denominator

Comment: I learned that I have to find an integrating factor in order to make it exact.

Comment: I know that if i use an integrating factor the form $\mu(y) = y$ it'll result in an exact equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am reminded of one saying that whenever things do not work out in one way, try the opposite way. That's what can be done here as well.

Given $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{y}{4y^2+2x}$. Then $\dfrac{dx}{dy}=-\dfrac{4y^2+2x}{y}\implies \dfrac{dx}{dy}+\dfrac{2x}{y}=-4y$. This gives I.F. as $y^2$ and the solution $xy^2=c-y^4$. Hope its clear.

Comment: wow that way is much easier

Comment: You should be able to see this small tricks when you solve these problems. It will come with practice. Since you are only 37 days into M.S.E. I worked this out.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let multiply both sides by $y$.

we get

$$\frac{d(y^2)}{dx}=\frac{2y^2}{y^2+2x}$$

put $\mu=y^2$

then

$$(\mu+2x)\mu'=2\mu$$

Comment: how did you find the $y$ as integrating factor ?